# Update data from one table in a database to another table in a different database not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to create a script that updates data from a table in one database to a table in another database.  I'm self-made and my abilities are very limited.  I'm sure there's a better way of doing this but it might be out of my reach.  Anyway, this is how I'm trying to do it.

The first document selects the data from the table I want to get the information from. It contains a link that allows me to select the row I want to copy. This link basically creates a form with the information I want to copy into the second database.  The idea is that when I press submit, it sends the information to the second database and it updates the fields.

The problem I'm having is that, even though it says it has executed the query successfully, it simply doesn't update the second database.

Can anyone see why this is not working?

These are the scripts I'm using:

TEST-DISPLAY.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="username"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db1"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="table1"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql </strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Uid</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>User Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Password</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Update</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><? echo $rows['uid']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['user']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['password']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>

// link to update.php and send value of id 
<td align="center"><a href="http://soundsurgery.co.uk/main/TEST5/TEST-EDIT.php?uid=<? echo $rows['uid']; ?>">update</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

TEST-EDIT.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="username"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db1"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="table1"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$uid=$_GET['uid'];

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE uid='$uid'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="TEST-EXEC.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Uid</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>User Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Password</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="uid" type="text" id="uid" value="<? echo $rows['uid']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="user" type="text" id="user" value="<? echo $rows['user']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="password" type="text" id="password" value="<? echo $rows['password']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<? echo $rows['email']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input name="uid" type="hidden" id="uid" value="<? echo $rows['uid']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

TEST-EXEC.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="username"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db2"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="table2"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET uname='$user', password='$password', email='$email' WHERE uid='$uid'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='TEST-DISPLAY2.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

TEST-DISPLAY2.php is the same as TEST-DISPLAY.php with the difference that it displays results for the second table.

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from PHP and it's dangerous when mis-used like you have. You're have some **severe** [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) here because you're not [properly escaping your values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will ensure your database code works in future versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eugenie, in TEST-EDIT.PHP you created a form in the script TEST-EXEC.PHP by the name of "form1" which uses the POST method.  Inside of form1 you are seeding the variables username, uid, password and email.  When you submit form1 it TEST-EXEC.PHP needs to capture the variables that you seeded.  You do this by:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

$_POST is a predefined variable that gets the values from a form sent with method="post". Put these at the top of TEST-EXEC.PHP.  You can also use $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
like another person mentioned so the values in variable user are escaped.

I am going to echo others and tell you that you have some serious security issues happening with this code because you are not paying attention to your strings.  If you do not research the security dangers people are mentioning then if you use this code in production you are opening up the entire database and webserver to malicious code. And it's just not worth it.

Here's something you need, it is a function that validates email addresses to make sure they do not contain bad things.

```
function validEmail($email)
{
   $isValid = true;
   $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
   if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
   {
      $isValid = false;
   }
   else
   {
      $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
      $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
      $localLen = strlen($local);
      $domainLen = strlen($domain);
      if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
      {
         // local part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
      {
         // domain part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
      {
         // local part starts or ends with '.'
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
      {
         // local part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
      {
         // character not valid in domain part
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
      {
         // domain part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if
(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                 str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
      {
         // character not valid in local part unless 
         // local part is quoted
         if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
             str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
         {
            $isValid = false;
         }
      }
    //  if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || ?checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
      if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
      {
         // domain not found in DNS
         $isValid = false;
      }
   }
   return $isValid;
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for this. Yes, I'm beginning to be a bit concerned about all the warnings.  All these scripts are for internal use, that is, for my own management of the site. It would not be open to the public.  I don't know if that makes a difference.  

You guys have scared me so I think I'll just stick to manual methods for the time being. Was just trying to do things easier for myself but it looks like I might end up paying a high price for it, so I'll wait until I can do things the right way.

Thanks everyone for your help and advice!!!

Comment: If this is only for your personal internal use don't worry about it, just take the time to learn best practise so you always write code properly in respect to security in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You're never setting the variables `$user`, `$password`, `$email`, or `$uid` in TEST-EXEC.php. You need:

```
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['uid']);

$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Notice that you use `$_GET` for parameters from the URL, `$_POST` for inputs from the form (unless the form uses `method="get"`).

Comment: See below for comment

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I'm having to build my site myself due to lack of funds and I'm just getting the code from the internet. Once you take me out of the very, very simple stuff, I haven't got a clue.  

How do I set the variables? I pasted your code and it just gives me a lot of errors.

Comment: That's how you set the variables. This code should be after `mysql_connect()` and before `mysql_query()`. There's only so much I can do to help someone who is totally clueless about programming, though. This site is not a replacement for knowing what you're doing; if you don't know how to program, you should find a different line of work, because that's a prerequisite for creating web sites.